# Using an existing address for another server

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, dns

Suppose that I have an account on a server with an address `http://www.xxx.xxx/~account`.

Because of some restriction on the server `xxx.xxx`, I set up a new AWS server with my own domain `http://my.domain.xxx`.

However, it looks like the new domain doesn't sufficiently represent my identity, so I was wondering if I could assign the address `http://www.xxx.xxx/~account` to the AWS server.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the A record of your www.xxx.xxx to the IP of the EC2 server hosting your website and set up a Virtual Host in your web server configuration to handle requests for that domain name.